# How to count backwards

Tags: javascript, for-loop, countdown, flip, snakecasing

Hey guys im developing something and I need to fix this please give me some feedback on how to improve this. (how to make it cleaner, easier to read , etc). Here's the code!

```
function wordFliper(word) {
    let wordOutput = "";
    let reverseIndex = word.length - 1;
    for (let index = reverseIndex; index >= 0; index--) {
      let storage = word[index];
      wordOutput = wordOutput + storage;
    }
    return wordOutput;
  }
```

Comment: Please request subjective feedback about your code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove some variables (variables that are used once in loop and then assigned to a function variable) to reduce code and rename one like this:

```
/// <summary>Function to flip words backwards</summary>
/// <param name="word" type="string">Word to be flipped</param>
/// <returns type="string">Word flipped</returns>

function wordFlipper(word) {
    let flippedWord = "";
    for (let i = word.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      flippedWord += word[i];
    }
    return flippedWord;
}
```

Also IMHO use i variable instead of index (for loop incrementer)

And Also get used to commenting your code, to know what is for the functions you're writing

I hope you helped to keep your code clean for further programming and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS array functions like reduce(),split(),reverse(), etc. You can write the code in following ways:

1. ```
   function wordFlipper(word) {
       return(word.split('').reverse().join(''));
   }
   ```
2. ```
   function wordFlipper(word) {
       return(word.split('').reduce((a,c)=>c+a));
   }
   ```

Please go through the links for clarity on the functions used above:

- split() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
- join() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join
- reverse() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse
- reduce() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: hey thanks! helped out!